# snap.svg moving object in a circle

Tags: javascript, animation, svg, path, snap.svg

I simply want to move a loaded SVG in a circle. 
Here is what i got so far, the idea being: "leave the object where it is, rotate it in a circle with a radius of 30":

```
var svgObject = Snap("svg#object g");
var path = svgObject.path("M0 0 a60 60 0 0 0 30 30");
var pathLength = path.getTotalLength();

Snap.animate(0, pathLength, function(value) {
   movePoint = path.getPointAtLength(value);
   svgObject.transform('t' + parseInt(movePoint.x) + ',' + parseInt(movePoint.y));
}, 5000, mina.easeOut);
```

I realize the code above must be relatively naive, but this is what I gathered from various sources on the internet.

All the above code does is move the object to the right. I want it to do a complete circle (ending exactly where it started).

What would I have to change to make the code above work as described?

Comment: Its not clear what problem you are actually experiencing. The code initially looks reasonable to move along a path (but incomplete), but what happens when it runs with whatever object you have ? You probably have a mistake in doing parseInt on a string with a comma in it, you probably want 2 parseInts one for each movePoint value as well.

Comment: @Ian I fixed the code (I didn't copy/paste it). There are actually 2 parseInt in there. You say the code is incomplete, what is missing? thx

Comment: The object that you want to move is missing, and the path isn't a circle. You possibly could just do a rotate transform around an offset centre as well, it depends if you mind the object itself being rotated or if it always wants to be upright. I would put it on a jsfiddle so we can see whats happening and any errors.

Comment: @Ian see this is what I do not get. How is the object missing? And what would the path look like if I wanted a complete circle? The Object itself cannot be rotated itself. It must stay as it is.

Comment: var svgObject = Snap("#object");// this line. What is #object ?

Comment: @Ian #object is the id of an svg group. it would normally be something like: svg#object g

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its always a lot easier if you include the full code and markup. Chances are you are trying to transform the main svg object (as I can see the code has been edited) and not transforming the g object. Also your path to animate along isn't right. As the markup isn't displayed, I can't test that, but here's a working example.

Just amend the circle path so it contains only the section you need.

```js
var svgObject = Snap("#svgobject");
var groupObject = Snap('#svgobject g');

var path = svgObject.path("M 100, 100m -75, 0a 75,75 0 1,0 150,0a 75,75 0 1,0 -150,0").attr({ fill: 'none' });


var pathLength = path.getTotalLength();

Snap.animate(0, pathLength, function(value) {
   movePoint = path.getPointAtLength(value);  
    
    groupObject.transform('t' + parseInt(movePoint.x) + ',' + parseInt(movePoint.y));
}, 5000, mina.easeOut);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/snap.svg/0.4.1/snap.svg-min.js"></script>

<svg id="svgobject" height="800" width="800">
    <g>
    <rect x="50" y="50" width="50" height="50"/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thank you, that was what I was looking for. Now I just have a few follow up questions concerning the path: How do I get the object to start rotating at the bottom and go to the top and then back to the bottom? and how do I change the direction of the rotation? I tried a couple of paths but all I managed was to make the rotation radius smaller.

Comment: You could probably animate from 1/2 the length of the circle back to 0 or whatever. Or create a new path with different start points.